# Error 404 al intentar hacer un httpget a un Action de un controller webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Agrego un `controller webapi`, el IDE se encarga de generar la clase `WebApiConfig` y de registrar las configuraciones en el `global.asax`, hasta aquí todo perfecto. Corro mi aplicación [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)  intento acceder a una `Action` de mi `controller` y obtengo un error 404.

Como ya tuve problemas de ruteo anteriormente (por desconocimiento) supongo que se debe a algo parecido.

### Mi WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

### Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

### Controller Webapi: `GerenciasController`

```
    public IEnumerable<Gerencia> Get()
    {
        ...
    }
```

Lo más curioso para mí es que tengo otro `controller` que si funciona, la diferencia es que en mi `get` le especifico un ruteo distinto al por defecto.

```
    [Route("api/Legajo/{idCompania}/{idLocal}/{fecha}")]
    public IEnumerable<Legajo> Get(short idCompania, short idLocal, string fecha)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Aclaro que estoy haciendo un `httpget`:

```
    $.getJSON('/api/Gerencias/', null, function (data) {
       ...
    });
```

También intenté desde mi browser directamente accediendo por la ruta:

```
http://misitio/api/Gerencias/
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El que no funciona es el que usa la ruta por defecto? ¿Que url estas usando para acceder ase `Action`?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz así es. Lo hago mediante el método `$.getJSON('/api/Gerencias/',...)` y también intento desde mi browser para descartar algun problema con mi script.

Comment: Y supongo que el controller se llama `GerenciasController` ?

Comment: si @CarlosMuñoz

Comment: Edite mi pregunta agregando esto que me consultas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré el problema, es el orden de registro de las configuraciones de ruteo. El `IDE` automáticamente te agrega todo al final (ver mi pregunta), esto ocasiona el mal funcionamiento mencionado.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    //Registrar aquí las configuraciones webapi
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


    //no registrar aquí las configuraciones webapi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que ese `Get()` debes invocarlo usando el verbo http correcto, solo ingresara a este si usaste un `GET` del http.

Usando el `GET` como verbo y la url `http://{sitio}/api/nombreController` deberia funcionar

Puedes usar [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) o [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) para probar el webapi.

Tambien intenta definir los atributos

```
[Route("api/Gerencias")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Gerencia> Get(){

}
```

Esto lo comento por lo que vi en este artículo

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Otra forma pdria ser

```
[Route("")]
public IEnumerable<Gerencia> Get(){

}
```

Analiza en el articulo el titulo "Route Prefixes" alli menciona esto que comento. Es mas alli en el controller define el atributo `[RoutePrefix("api/books")]`

Comment: así es @Leandro lo estoy haciendo mediante un `GET`. Tal vez faltó aclararlo en mi pregunta. Es muy curioso lo que sucede, ya que no veo nada raro.

Comment: @Alan como defines la url ? lo haces como indico en la respuesta, pones api/nombrecontroller?  Con que tools estas probando invocar la webapi?

Comment: edité mi pregunta aclarando mas cuestiones.

Comment: @Alan edite la respuesta

Comment: Sigue igual @Leandro.

Comment: Si realizas un Rebuild de la solucion y cierras el IIS Express, tampoco lo toma?

Comment: Intenta usando [Route("api/Legajo")] he invocalo con un GET pero la url  http://{sitio}/api/Legajo

Comment: ya encontré la solución, perdon pero no pude pasar estos días a dejarla.

Comment: @Alan que bueno, cual fue el problema ?

Comment: ahí agregué mi respuesta, gracias @Leandro  por la predisposición.

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo adicionando la etiqueta acción en la propiedad *routerTemplate*, por ejemplo:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, pero no era ese el problema sino el orden de los Registers.