# Web API Default Route no funciona cuando recibe parametro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, configuración

Estoy usando Web Api 2.0 junto con MVC 5

Este es mi WebApiConfig

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Este es mi controller:

```
public class PartesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int? id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HornosContext db = new HornosContext())
            {
                if (id == null || id == 0)
                {
                    return Ok(db.Partes.ToList());
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(db.HornosPartes.Where(ph => ph.IdHorno == id).Select(ph => ph.Parte).ToList());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

- Al llamar `http://blabla/api/partes/1` Funciona
- Al llamar `http://blabla/api/partes` me da `404 NOT FOUND`

Si quito el parametro de la accion:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HornosContext db = new HornosContext())
            {
                return Ok(db.Partes.ToList());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

y mando a llamar el metodo asi: `http://blabla/api/partes` Funciona.

**Por que Web API no me esta identificando el id como un valor opcional?**

**EDIT:**

Se que puedo agregar atributos y mas acciones, pero siendo algo tan sencillo, quisiera que esto funcione con las rutas predeterminadas.

En la pregunta sugerida como duplicada el problema tiene que ver con el orden de registro de las configuraciones de ruteo, aqui lo resolvi especificando un valor predeterminado al parametro de la accion (ver respuesta abajo)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Error 404 al intentar hacer un httpget a un Action de un controller webapi](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/error-404-al-intentar-hacer-un-httpget-a-un-action-de-un-controller-webapi)

Comment: Fijate en el register en el global.asax en que orden lo estás haciendo. fijate esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3487/225

Comment: @Alan Ye publique la respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo tuve que especificar un valor predeterminado al parámetro del método y funcionó

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get(int? id = null)
 {
  .....
```

Answer (score 4):

Si usas `Web Api 2` usa atributos para mapear usando el `[Route]` de esta forma podrias crear dos action recibiendo o no el `id`

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
public class PartesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/partes/{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HornosContext db = new HornosContext())
            {
                return Ok(db.HornosPartes.Where(ph => ph.IdHorno == id).Select(ph => ph.Parte).ToList());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }

    [Route("api/partes")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HornosContext db = new HornosContext())
            {
                return Ok(db.Partes.ToList());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero esto es lo que quiero evitar, recuerdo que esto se podia hacer sin tener que usar atributos ni agregando mas metodos

Comment: pero si lo realizas de esta forma te funciona? al menos para que quede claro que es un tema con el routing

Comment: Tengo otros metodos GET y POST con parametros y attribute routing que si funcionan

Comment: Crea un proyecto webapi nuevo y analiza como te defien los metodos Get(), veras que la forma en que lo realizas no es la correcta, deberias tener dos metodo uno con parametro y otro sin este. Pueden tener el nismo nombre y los atributos son opcionales, pero no crees un unico metodo con parametro opcional.

Comment: Ya publique la respuesta, gracias por la ayuda +1